# Useful software for variable elimination

Tags: polynomials, computer-algebra, mathematical-software, elimination-theory, software

I have three non-homogeneous trivariate polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x,y,z]$ and I want to eliminate the variables $y$ and $z$ to get a polynomial in $x$. The monomials of the polynomials are $\{1,x^4,x^2,x^2y,x^2z\}$ and I want to reduce to univariate polynomial over $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Is there an automatic algorithm for these purposes?

Is there any useful python library package available?

If not what is the best software for these tasks?

Comment: Btw, this problem can be posed as iterative computing of [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Elimination_property): $$\mathrm{res}_y(\mathrm{res}_z(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z)),\mathrm{res}_z(f_1(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z))).$$

Comment: Usually taking iterated resultants like this produces extraneous factors, as figured out by Etienne Bezout. One should take the multivariate resultant with respect to the pair (y,z).

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Can you explain as answer below on what is meant by multivariate resultant?

Comment: See my answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51534/multipolynomial-resultants/51583#51583

Answer (score 6):

This can be done, e.g., in SageMath - here are [documentation and examples](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_ideal.html). The code can be run online at [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Comment: Would there be any python package?

Comment: Not sure what python package you mean, but SageMath is python-based and it can be used as a python module.

Comment: Actually it seemed I can use 'linear algebra' to eliminate monomial $x^2y$ and then $x^2z$ since $y$ and $z$ depends only on these monomials. Is that correct way to do?

Comment: In your case, yes. You can view your polynomials as linear combinations of $1, y, z$ with coefficients being polynomials in $x$, then you'd need to form a $3\times 3$ matrix with those coefficients and compute its determinant.

Comment: The specific Sage command you're after is "elimination_ideal", see https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_ideal.html#sage.rings.polynomial.multi_polynomial_ideal.MPolynomialIdeal_singular_repr.elimination_ideal

Answer (score 1):

You can also eliminate variables using Mathematica.
There is a dedicated stackexchange for Mathematica, so if you post your problem there, someone might even solve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Several software packages can do this (SageMath, Mathematica, Maple, CoCoA, etc.). For Python, I've found https://github.com/mlweiss/buchberger_algorithms, by Michael Weiss. See the accompanying [PDF](https://github.com/mlweiss/buchberger_algorithms/blob/master/buchberger_implementation.pdf) for some explanation.

For more on this topic, see *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* or its sequel *Using Algebraic Geometry* by Cox, Little & O'Shea. Cox's website for the first book is: https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/iva.html. You can also look up Buchberger's algorithm and Gröbner bases (e.g. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Buchberger%27s_algorithm).